# Are arrays in structs freed on deletion?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, struct

If I were to use something like this in C++,

```
struct socket_t {
    sockaddr_in address;
    char buffer[2048];
    int FD;
}

socket_t *clients[256];
memset(clients, 0, 256);
```

and then create objects in it,

```
socket_t **free = (socket_t**) memchr(clients, 0, 256);
*free = new socket_t;
```

and then use **delete** on some of the elements,

```
delete clients[index];
```

would all members be safely freed (especially the buffer)?

I don't want to waste 2 KiB on each item I create.

I'm asking this because I noticed **sizeof** returns the amount of bytes used when an array is declared with `type[2048]` but the size of the pointer if it's declared with `type*`.

Comment: `free` is the name of an existing function, don't use it as variable name!

Comment: `memset( clients, 0, 256 );` will clear 256 bytes, not 256 clients.

Comment: @Bo Persson would `memset( clients, 0, sizeof clients );` fix that?

Comment: This looks like a bad idea. Could you say what you *want& to achieve, and we can perhaps think of some nicer solutions?

Comment: @KerrekSB set a server up for chat that allows large amounts of clients. I use separate processes for reading from each client because  `read` blocks, and reading to the same buffer simultaneously is risky, and I don't want to use up a half GiB for just a few clients.

Comment: @RPFeltz: So why not something like `struct socket_t { std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf; int fd; socket_t(size_t n) : buf(new char[n]) { } };`...?

Comment: @KerrekSB So how's that supposed to fix it?

Comment: @RPFeltz: I don't know if there's anything to "fix" -- are you preallocating all the sockets? You can modify the structure to have a no-op constructor and only "enable" the socket on demand.

Comment: If you want to allow for *large amounts of clients*, you might want to consider using `select` rather than launching threads for each client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array in your struct is an automatic object, whose life-time is tied with the instance of struct. So yes, when you delete an instance of the struct, the memory of the array is also *automatically* freed. This is true for all *non-pointer* members.

Comment: With the right notion, you could say it's true for *all* members -- the pointers themselves are also freed (since the pointers are automatic, too); only *the objects they point at* are not touched. :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB: Correct, but that is too geeky; so I avoided saying that. But I hope that he would read your comment.

Comment: @Nawaz I did, and I know that, but I wondered because I heard all arrays are pointers. Or if you're talking about it being a bad idea, I just replied about a minute ago.

Comment: @RPFeltz: Arrays are not pointers; they can behave like pointers in some context.