# Deallocating a struct containing string variables

Tags: c++, struct, delete-operator

I have the following struct

```
struct node
{
string name;
bool   isDir;
int    size;
string data; //lets store this as a string
timespec atime;
timespec ctime;
timespec mtime;
list <node*> children;

};
```

If I have a declare a node pointer like

```
node * directory = new node;
```

and then 
populate it with values

and then finally use

```
delete directory; //c++ construct
```

will all the memory space be freed? I'm particularly interested to know if the strings are automatically deallocated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you delete a node, all of its automatical objects' destructors will be called, including that of the std::strings, which will indeed deallocate themselves, like other STL containters like the std::list in you struct would.

However, the children nodes, or any other heap objects, won't be destroyed unless you delete them yourself, for exemple by creating a destructor for your Node object, ie:

```
struct Node {
    ...
    list<Node*> mChildren;
    virtual ~Node() {
        for(auto& child : mChildren) delete child;
    }
}
```

Deleting an object first calls it's destructor, so calling delete on a child node will make it delete it's children nodes, and so on recursively until the leaves.

If the graph is a tree, the modern code would use unique_ptr to automatically destroy a node's children when the node is destroyed :

```
struct Node {
    ...
    list<unique_ptr<Node>> mChildren;
}
```

Indeed, unique_ptr assume unique ownership, as such, when their automatic unique_ptr container gets destroyed, they delete their contained pointer's pointed object, which might then destroy it's children recursively, if you built it that way.

You could also use shared_ptr for more complex graph structures, but obviously the problem is that you then need to take care of cyclic references, ie, nodes should only have weak_ptr to the root node in order to not invalidly increasing it's refcount and invalidly making the object's life unlimited.

Comment: Just to make things clearer.Strings and other containers are allocated in heap?

Comment: they are allocated in the stack and store their contained objects in the heap, afaik. Actual implementation of the containers is undefined (aka, compiler provider's choice)

Comment: Well this answers it! Thanks guys!

Comment: Np. please consider accepting the answer if it answers your question

Comment: by clicking on the gray outline for a check mark under the answer score

Answer (score 1):

[Are arrays in structs freed on deletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367741/are-arrays-in-structs-freed-on-deletion?rq=1)

> The array in your struct is an automatic object, whose life-time is
>   tied with the instance of struct. So yes, when you delete an instance
>   of the struct, the memory of the array is also automatically freed.
>   **This is true for all non-pointer members.**